# Speed up MU Wordpress on Apache VPS?

Tags: multisite, plugin-w3-total-cache, vps, apc

I have a wordpress multisite 3.6 with 1 main site and 5 subdomains(with mapping domains)

I am tried to make it faster, i install the W3 Total Cache plugin

i add on my apache the APC 3.1.13
yum install httpd-devel
pecl install apc

> Enable internal debugging in APC [no] : no Enable per request file
>
> info about files used from the APC cache [no] : no Enable spin locks
>
> (EXPERIMENTAL) [no] : no Enable memory protection (EXPERIMENTAL) [no]: no Enable pthread mutexes (default) [no] : yes Enable pthread
>
> read/write locks (EXPERIMENTAL) [yes] : no

edit php.ini after line eaccelerator.shm_ttl="0"

```
apc.enabled="1"
apc.shm_segments="1"
apc.shm_size="128"
apc.ttl="7200"
apc.user_ttl="7200"
apc.num_files_hint="1024"
apc.mmap_file_mask="/tmp/apc.XXXXXX"
apc.enable_cli="1"
```

and on my shh add this command lines

```
service httpd restart

php -r 'phpinfo();' | grep 'apc'
```

but i can see big difference :/

**on gtmetrix (but is not solid everytime that i test)**

**Before**

B (82%)

D (62%)

7.88s

1.67MB

118

**After**

A (92%) +10%

C (73%) +11%

5.33s -2.55s

1.33MB -344KB

101 -17

**on pingdom (but is not solid everytime that i test)**

**Before**

Page size

1.5MB

Load time

3.78s

Requests

133

**After**

Page size

1.2MB

Load time

2.58s

Requests

129

This my [phpinfo](http://pastebin.com/aae6GxWG) and this [my w3 total case setup](http://pastebin.com/GuYnRSdV)

what I have done wrong and i have something else to add on my server or on my multisite?

Comment: Sorry? Your performance numbers improved. What do you think is wrong?

Comment: i test my self with a timer, 2,5-2,8s takes when i click on a post to refresh to full post and another 3s to full loading the full post (totaly 5,6-6s). and before all this i have the same loading time

Comment: I wouldn't trust manual timing if I were you. The "after" numbers you posted are better. What is the URL for the site?

Comment: yes, of course is very better the "after" numbers but when i'm surfing my site i don't see big differences before a add all this, how can i sent you private my url plz?

Comment: This is a public forum. You don't send it "private". Post the URL if you want me to look into it. Chances are, though, that your site has architectural problems that will take a lot of hands on work to fix.

Answer (score 2):

I checked your site with webpagetest.org :

http://www.webpagetest.org/result/130803_C5_3FE9/1/details/

You are loading a lot of information from a lot of different places-- Facebook, Google, Twitter, Pinterest, doublclick... You are loading something like 80 resources from remote locations (To be honest, I lost count but that is in the ballpark). That is more than half-- 55-60%-- of the resources your page loads.

The only things that W3 Total Cache and APC can help with are the things that load from your server. Those things load pretty quickly, with the exception of some css (looks like) from the "WP Filebase" plugin, which takes about 1.8 seconds to load all by itself, but it *does* cache so it is better on subsequent page loads.

If you are going to improve page load time you are in for a significant structural overhaul. You need to take a close look at what you need and what you don't and remove what you don't. You need to try to improve the efficiency of what you do keep but that is a dozen questions in itself.

This is not a WordPress problem, nor a W3 Total Cache problem, nor an APC problem. You are just doing a *lot* and are dependent on a lot of third party servers to do it.